# How to customize drupal web services error messages

Tags: services

I am working in web services for ecommerce project, in that i want to customize or remove HTML Tags from drupal error messages., in user module.

See my code in below:

```
if ($errors = form_get_errors()) {
    $return = new stdClass();
    $return->body = 'null';
    $return->message = "Failed to register user.";
    $return->error = implode(" ", $errors); 
    $return->status = 500;

    return $return;
}
```

My response error message is:

```
{  
       "body":"null",
       "message":"Failed to register user.",
       "error":"Username field is required. The e-mail address <em class=\"placeholder\">user1@jc.com</em> is already registered. <a href=\"/zee/homechef2/user/password\">Have you forgotten your password?</a>",
       "status":500
    }
```

error contains some HTML tags, so i want to remove or customize that tags.

Anyone have any idea please share here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `strip_tags` function to remove HTML Tags,. partially fixed.